# Snowflake data loading from local system to Stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-stage

I want to load data from my local system to Snowflake. So each time when a file arrives in my local folder would like to push that to the snowflake stage. I have checked for multiple approaches but not fruitful.I Can anyone suggest a method for this?.
I can use snowpipe to push the data from stage to snowflake table but not able to find an approach to push the data in my local system to the snowflake stage.

There is no proper approach to do this task when i browsed the internet

Comment: You would need to write a batch file that checks for the presence of a local file and, if it finds one, runs a SnowSQL command to PUT that file into a stage. How to write that file would depend on your local system (Windows, Mac, Linux, etc)

Comment: Thank you @NickW.But i am not able to find any relevant documentation or steps in google.Could you please share any if you have?

Comment: You need to research creating script files on your local system, whatever that is (e.g. .bat or PowerShell scripts if you are using Windows)

Comment: Yes i got it. Created a .bat file and used a task scheduler to trigger it. Thank you for your help :)